# Problema con la visualización del logo de la aplicación en notificaciones en dispositivos Android

Tags: flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En mi aplicación desarrollada en FlutterFlow. El inconveniente se relaciona con la visualización del logo de la aplicación cuando llega una notificación en dispositivos Android reales y emulador.

He revisado la documentación proporcionada por FlutterFlow, pero no he encontrado una solución específica para este problema. Me gustaría saber si alguien más ha experimentado este problema y si ha encontrado una solución efectiva

Las notificaciones llegan correctamente a los dispositivos Android reales y emulador.
Sin embargo, el logo de la aplicación no se muestra en las notificaciones, lo cual es un inconveniente importante para brindar una experiencia consistente a los usuarios.
He revisado la configuración relacionada con las notificaciones en FlutterFlow, pero no he encontrado ninguna opción específica para controlar la visualización del logo en las notificaciones.
Me aseguré de que el logo de la aplicación esté correctamente configurado en mi proyecto de FlutterFlow.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien ha enfrentado este mismo problema en sus aplicaciones desarrolladas en FlutterFlow o en Flutter en general? Si es así, ¿pudieron encontrar una solución para asegurar que el logo de la aplicación se muestre correctamente en las notificaciones en dispositivos Android?

Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda o consejo que puedan proporcionar. ¡Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y asistencia!

imagen de los asents: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Su ícono de notificación debe ser blanco y transparente sin colores. Puede utilizar esta herramienta para hacerlo: [icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)

Comment: "Utiliza los comentarios para pedir mas informacion o para sugerir mejoras. Evitar responder a preguntas en los comentarios." Para quien cambió mi respuesta a un comentario, lo anterior es la respuesta. No es un comentario.

Comment: Gracias Scott, el detalle es que estoy usando Flutterflow para el desarrollo de la app y como se muestra en la captura de pantalla "App Assents" no existe un icono para notificaciones en las opciones de carga. Talvez no estoy en el lugar indicado o talvez el Launcher Icon debe ser transparente. Probaré .

Comment: En su pantalla de notificaciones de Flutterflow hay un lugar Notification Image (optional) - Upload Notification Image. Creo que este es el lugar para tu ícono. En Android este icono debería ser transparente. Utilice una herramienta como en el enlace anterior al crearlo.

Comment: Excelente ya me di cuenta del error. Sucede que FlutterFlow utiliza el mismo logotipo que se carga en "App Assents/Loucher Icon" para convertirlo en formato sin color. Pe por lo que es necesario subir un icono con fondo transparente. Me gustaría encontrar la manera de que se use otro icono de forma personalizada. Ya que mi icono es de fondo azul. Y quiero seguir usando el mínimo ícono.